# Why does * and % behave differently in this rule?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make each object file `foo.o` dependent on its source file `foo.c`.  For some reason, using * to make each dependent on every source file (so that `foo.o` depends on `foo.c, bar.c, etc.` works but using % gives an error.

My directory structure is has just one source file right now, but I'm planning to add more. The error I get is:

```
$(PATHO)%.o:: $(PATHT)*.c  # This compiles properly
  recipe

$(PATHO)%.o:: $(PATHT)%.c  # This causes error 'No rule to make target'
  recipe
```

EDIT: I clarified my question, apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Why the double colon `::`? One would work.

Comment: What do you mean by "this works" and "this fails"? What actually happens? Please provide example output and explain what you want it to do differently.

Comment: Your language is very confusing. Your first sentence suggests that you want each object to depend on all sources, your second makes that explicitly clear, your code confirms that, and your last sentence seems to contradict it (and is self-contradictory when taken literally), And if you want that, *for Heaven's sake WHY?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `%` in a target pattern matches, the `%` in the prerequisites expand to the matched part in the target.

For example, let's say you have a rule

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
```

When `foo.o` matches the rule target (`%.o`), the prerequisite is `foo.c`.

This is explained in for example the GNU Make manual, section [Introduction to Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html), and works the same in all make variants.